# dojo.xhrPost Not Sending any Data

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, dojo

I'm just getting into Dojo and wanted to try a simple AJAX Post like the [examples](http://dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/hello-world-tutorial) on 
Dojo's website.

Here is the HTML/JS:

```
<form method="POST" id="addProjectForm">
<dl>
    <dt>Project Name:</dt>
        <dd><input dojoType="dijit.form.TextBox" id="projectName"></dd>
    <dt>Project Description:</dt>
        <dd><textarea dojoType="dijit.form.Textarea" id="projectDescription" style="width: 300px; height: 100px"></textarea></dd>
</dl>

<button dojoType="dijit.form.Button" style="float: right">
    Save Project
    <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick">
        dojo.xhrPost({
            url: '/projects/add/',
            load: function(data, ioArgs) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data, ioArgs) {
                alert('There was an error');
            },
            form: 'addProjectForm'
        });
    </script>
</button>
</form>
```

and on the backend I have the following:

```
class ProjectsController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
public function addAction()
{
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);

    $projectName    = $this->_request->getParam('projectName');
    $description    = $this->_request->getParam('projectDescription');

    print_r($_POST);
}
}
```

When I click the 'Save Project' button, I get a JS alert box with php output of an empty array so none of the information is getting posted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of a stupid mistake. I didn't have a name set on any of the form elements, only IDs.

Answer (score 0):

As I have been playing with POSTing data through Dojo last night, I have one small remark.

*dojo.xhrPost()* seem only to work in last version of Dojo Toolkit, when using previous versions you are locked to *dojo.io.iframe.send()*, if you want to handle the response server gives you after POSTing data. Documentation is bit unclear on this.